# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar una consulta sql de firebird desde javascript dentro de un bucle?

Tags: javascript, express, firebird

Tengo la consulta dentro del bucle, pero simplemente no entra a la consulta. este es el código de js, desconozco si se pueden ejecutar consultas dentro de bucles, la razón por la cual la hice así es por que la variable codigo es dinámica y solo quiero que me traiga los resultados donde el código coincida, pero la variable código viene de un arreglo, este arreglo es de prueba, el original contiene 1200 códigos es por eso que quiero hacerla dinámica

[
"Tl30001",
"286364",
"Wk850/1",
"14716"
]
esta lista viene del archivo json test.json

````
const Firebird = require('node-firebird');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

app.get("/api/claves", (req, res) => { // Leer el archivo de test.json

    let publicaciones = []
    fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', (err, publicacionesArticulos) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error al leer el archivo test.json', err);
            return;
        }


        try { // Convertir los datos del archivo JSON a objetos JavaScript
            publicaciones = JSON.parse(publicacionesArticulos);
            console.log(publicaciones);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al parsear los archivos JSON', error);
        }

        
        Firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {

            if (err) {
                console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).json({error: 'Error connecting to the database', target: err});
            }

            publicaciones.forEach((item) => {
                console.log(item);
    
                // Realiza la consulta a la tabla
                db.query("SELECT CODIGO FROM ARTICULOS WHERE CODIGO = ?",[item], (err, result) => {
                    console.log('etro al query ');
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error al ejecutar la consulta', err);
                        console.log(err);
                        return res.status(500).json({error: 'Error al ejecutar la consulta', target: err});
                    }
    
                    // Cierra la conexión a la base de datos
                    db.detach((err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error('Error al desvincular database:', err);
                            console.log(err);
                            return res.status(500).json({error: 'Error al cerrar la conexion con la db', target: err})
                        }
    
                        // Escribe el resultado en un archivo JSON
                        const jsonResult = JSON.stringify(result);
                        fs.writeFile('mercado.json', jsonResult, (err) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error('Error al escribir el archivo JSON', err);
                                console.log(err);
                                return res.status(500).json({error: 'Error al escribir el archivo JSON', target: err});
                            }
                            console.log('Archivo JSON creado exitosamente');
                        });
                    });
    
                    // Devuelve los resultados como respuesta
                    res.json(result);
    
                });
                
            });

            
        })

    });
}); ```
````

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir exactamente que "no entra a la consulta"?